# explain some code about moving text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was in search of How get moving text in widget with given width ?
and I found a good work in :

[How get moving text in widget with given width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716719/how-get-moving-text-in-widget-with-given-width)

but I don't understand `startTimer` method.
if it is possible , someone explain this method:
Thanks alot.

```
  void startTimer() {
    if (_key.currentContext != null) {
      double widgetWidth =
          _key.currentContext.findRenderObject().paintBounds.size.width;
      double widgetHeight =
          _key.currentContext.findRenderObject().paintBounds.size.height;

      timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: _timerRest), (timer) {
        double maxScrollExtent = scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
        double pixels = scrollController.position.pixels;
        if (pixels + _moveDistance >= maxScrollExtent) {
          if (widget.scrollAxis == Axis.horizontal) {
            position = (maxScrollExtent -
                        screenWidth * widget.ratioOfBlankToScreen +
                        widgetWidth) /
                    2 -
                widgetWidth +
                pixels -
                maxScrollExtent;
          } else {
            position = (maxScrollExtent -
                        screenHeight * widget.ratioOfBlankToScreen +
                        widgetHeight) /
                    2 -
                widgetHeight +
                pixels -
                maxScrollExtent;
          }
          scrollController.jumpTo(position);
        }
        position += _moveDistance;
        scrollController.animateTo(position,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: _timerRest), curve: Curves.linear);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The startTimer every _timerRest milliseconds tells to the scrollController to jumpTo a new position, if the text arrives to the end it starts over.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is _key.currentContext and key.currentContext.findRenderObject().paintBounds.size.width

Comment: The _key is the GlobalKey we are using to refere to the ListView, in the example in the link you mentión is used in the ListView. With that GlobalKey we can refer to it to know the size of the ListView to make calculations.