# Flutter - make Text() glide if its too long

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-text

So basically I want to make a widget that checks how much space is available and if there is not enough space to wait a few seconds and then slowly glide and stop at the start position. This process should repeat forever and optimally don't use too much performance. If did not get a clear idea of how I want the widget to behave, just look at the Spotify song names.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Include the code in your question.

Comment: actually I am pretty new to flutter and I don't know how to go on, but I've tried to create a custom scroll view but this did not work so I deleted it

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AnimationController with a custom animation which moves a Positioned widget containing the Text widget to make your own ScrollingText widget. There's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716719/how-get-moving-text-in-widget-with-given-width) where this exact problem gets covered in more detail. You can just copy-paste the code from there and you should be good.